# How Do I Use The Pre-Deploy AWS CDK Hook?

Tags: testing, aws-cdk

**Use-Case**:

To run the tests before the `CLI` deploys the changed resources.

I've seen this `preDeploy` hook available in the AWS CDK [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_cloud-assembly-schema.Hooks.html).

```js
// The code below shows an example of how to instantiate this type.
// The values are placeholders you should change.
import * as cloud_assembly_schema from '@aws-cdk/cloud-assembly-schema';
const hooks: cloud_assembly_schema.Hooks = {
  postDeploy: ['postDeploy'],
  postDestroy: ['postDestroy'],
  preDeploy: ['preDeploy'],
  preDestroy: ['preDestroy'],
};
```

However, I am unsure how to use it. I've also seen, [integration testing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/integ-tests-alpha-readme.html) and the [IntegTest construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_integ-tests-alpha.IntegTest.html) from which I've been told can work together.

**Example:**

I have this test which tests to see whether all the `lambdaProperties` have a `key` of `Code`.

```js
it("Code", () => lambdaProperties.forEach(el => expect(el["Code"]).toBeDefined()));
```

**Requirements:**

1. User types `cdk deploy` in the `CLI`
2. All the tests run
3. If the tests pass, `cdk deploy` can happen. Else, it does not continue.

Comment: I might be missing the point but why hooks? Wouldn't regular sequence "synthesize stacks, run tests, deploy stacks" work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** The `preDeploy` hook runs in the context of a [CDK integration test](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/integ-tests-alpha-readme.html). Such tests, run with the separately-packaged [integ-runner](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/@aws-cdk/integ-runner/README.md) CLI, actually *deploy test stacks* to the cloud. The test runner invokes the hook before the test stacks are deployed. These tests and hooks are unrelated to the `cdk deploy` command.

---

The experimental `@aws-cdk/integ-tests-alpha` package's integration tests perform snapshot tests, deploy test stacks and can perform [assertions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/integ-tests-alpha-readme.html#assertions) on deployed resources. Here's a minimal example with a [hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_cloud-assembly-schema.Hooks.html#interface-hooks) option, which are *"Additional commands to run at predefined points in the test workflow"*:

```js
// integ.my-app.ts

import { IntegTest } from "@aws-cdk/integ-tests-alpha";

const app = new cdk.App();

new IntegTest(app, "Integ", {
  testCases: [myStack],
  hooks: {
    preDeploy: ['npm test'], // <-- run unit tests before the test stacks are deployed
  },
  cdkCommandOptions: {
    deploy: {
      args: {
        profile: "my-test-profile",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Run the tests with the [integ-runner](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/tree/main/packages/%40aws-cdk/integ-runner) CLI.  It runs tests patterned `/integ.*.js$/` in the `test` dir [by default](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/@aws-cdk/integ-runner/README.md#usage).  With the options below, it deploys the test stack to `us-east-1` and destroys it when the tests finish:

```bash
integ-runner --parallel-regions us-east-1
```

---

In other words, hooks won't fulfil your requirements, as they are unrelated to `cdk deploy`<sup>1</sup>. However, a good old-fashioned `package.json` script like `"deploy": "npm test && cdk deploy"` will do the trick.  Or, equivalently, using a [pre-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts):

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "predeploy": "npm test",
    "deploy": "cdk deploy",
}
```

---

[1] Note that [all references](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/search?q=preDeploy&type=code) to `preDeploy` in the CDK source code relate to integration tests.

Comment: How would I ensure when someone writes `cdk deploy`, the tests run first?

Comment: @Luke The goal is a good one, but cloud-side enforcement is more robust than client-side monkey patches.  Consider a [pipeline](https://pipelines.devops.aws.dev/application-pipeline/ri-cdk-pipeline/) setup. Deny all deploy- and destroy-related actions in your prod account, except those coming from the pipeline.  The pipeline would have a test stage before the deploy stage.

Comment: Thank you for answering, fedonev. How does one deny all deploy and destroy-related actions?

Comment: @Luke  Glad to help.  Short answer, a [Cross-account pipeline + IAM policies](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/).